# How do I stop a Rect drawing in WPF if it's empty?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, drawing

This feels like it should be something really simple, but I can't get this to work.

I have a `<Rectangle>` on a `<Canvas>`, where the `DataContext` on the `<Rectangle>` is bound to a `Rect`, and I'm trying to draw it with `<Rectangle>` attributes `Canvas.Left="{Binding Left}"` and `Width="{Binding Width}"` (similar for the vertical components).

This is fine if there's a rectangle there, but in the case where the bound `Rect` is empty (i.e., `IsEmpty == True`), it's giving me lots of `Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property` errors with the infinite values.

I've tried setting the `Visibility` to `Collapsed` using a data trigger on the `IsEmpty` property setting the visibility to collapsed, I've tried doing the same on the parent canvas, but no matter what I do I'm still getting these binding expression errors.

Is there any way at all to simply get it to 'don't even try drawing this if it's empty'?

Comment: Is the binding error relative to Canvas.Left or Width properties?

Comment: Both. And the verticals. I get four errors every time.

Comment: I think that you could use a converter that, when property from rect isn't valid, it returns Zero. Or give a try to the answer, it looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I fixed a similar issue with something like this:

```
<Rectangle Canvas.Left="{Binding Left}"
       Canvas.Top="{Binding Top}">
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEmpty}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>             
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style> 
    </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```

So, basically "breaking" the binding to the invalid `DataContext` value and setting a fixed value in XAML.

> Note: this is handwritten XAML, might contain syntax errors.

Comment: I actually did this the other way round- I checked if the binding was False, and set the position/dimensions if it was. Thanks!